# Getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" upon execution of selenium script

Tags: selenium, testng

Kindly can anyone help about the root cause of below exception.

## Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   Test_Automation.TC_Invoice_Printing.TC_input_fields_validation(TC_Invoice_Printing.java:37)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

**Script:**

```
@Test
public void TC_input_fields_validation() {

        int default_input_fields_count = Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'input-lg form-control')]")).size();
        System.out.println("default field count" + default_input_fields_count);
        System.out.println(Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a")).isDisplayed());
        Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a")).click();
        Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a")).click();
        Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a")).click();
}
```

Comment: driver is null. What is the code in Invoke_Test_Instance to initialize the driver variable?

Comment: Dear Grasshopper- thanks for your reply. Infact the issue got resolved by inserting method related to web driver initialisation within method defined under @BeforeClass

Comment: @Ali - Please add what worked for you as an answer to your question and please accept it, so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by inserting method related to web driver initialisation within method defined under @BeforeClass